# Log.d can not log total message in Android Studio

Tags: android, logging, console

Using Log.d() on Android Studio, I print a relatively long json, only a part of it is displayed, and I want to view the complete one, what should I do?

Ofcourse, separating the content is a way we can think of directly, but isn't it not so cool?

Answer (score 0):

You can break the answer into chunks and display them one by one:

```
var str = jsonObj.toString()
var k = 1000; //or a smaller value, idk..
for (i in 0..str.length step k) {
    Log.d(yourTag, str.substring(i, minOf(i + k, str.length)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But isn't there any senior function?

Comment: I don't think there is. But you can increase `k` I think up to 4000. Have you tried the solution? Isn't it readable?

Comment: Haha, ofcourse I know the meaning of the loop code.